# Update creates a new entity instead of updating the current one on Google's Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-cloud-datastore

Working on an app in python deployed over the google app engine.

Here is the code i used to do the update.

```
key = ndb.Key('User', uid)
        user = key.get()
        if not user:
            logging.info("Creating new user...")
            user = M.User(id=uid)
        user.remind = tmp
        user.put()
```

Instead of updating the old entity, a new entity is created with the key as a in the name field. As seen below
Name/ID classNo created first_name  groupid last_name   remind  updated username

id=133877436    0 2016-08-13 (15:16:04.890) HKT JIACHENNN null true 2016-08-13 (15:19:49.055) HKT

name=133877436  -1 2016-08-13 (15:19:52.590) HKT null null null true 2016-08-13 (15:19:52.590) HKT null

Appreciate any help!

UPDATE/SOLVED

solved it by using the int(uid) when fetching the entity. It was creating a mew entity because the two keys was different. One was 133877436 and was was enclosed in quotes  '133877436' hence name was called.

Hope this helps someone else

Comment: You don't show how this code is being called, but `id=133866436` is a long, `name=133866436` is a string, so the keys are different. If the keys are different, the entities will be different.

Comment: @jiachen: you should add an answer to your question with the solution - to not leave the question appear as unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to update an entity you ought to retrieve this entity by his id, then you can change the old value. For exemple:

```
entity_to_edit = Entity.get_by_id(this_entit_id)
entity_to_edit.some_attribute = "new_variable"
entity_to_edit.put()
```